# PHP hangs on multiple requests

Tags: php

Hi everyone I have a problem.

I have made a script where user submits a details. Details are saved to database
and a exec is called after they are saved. The background scipt that is called is a php
script that I call it via exec with wget:

```
session_write_close();
@exec('wget -q  -o /dev/null -a /dev/null -O /home/linux/test.txt http://127.0.0.1/admin/install.php?s=' . session_id() . '  > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

the script queries database and posts some parameters to external url with curl and waits for response.

I am unable to open any other php page (status bar shows: waiting for 127.0.0.1) on the webserver until the script execution of the script above ends. What I want is to run in background while I do other things on my website.

Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny9 with Suhosin-Patch Server at 127.0.0.1
Debian Linux distro.
Server API  CGI/FastCGI

Comment: Even if I call it via the php cli the same problem appears.

Answer (score 1):

http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php

I assume you want server script to wait with sleep() timed interval for an AJAX event to trigger a server response / polling. Use session_write_close() before each sleep() iteration to make it work. I did a simple online chat using this pattern and it worked as charm.

The crucial thing was to prevent receiver AJAX script from constantly polling the server for updates in order to get fast response. Instead it requests script which sleeps and doesn't send any response untill reasonable timeout or an event occurs on server side.

Comment: It still hangs despite session_write_close()? Anyway, I suspect exec() would wait for the command to complete, maybe popen() would be a better solution if you want to really start the command in background?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using file based sessions, they will lock the pages until they have been closed at end of script or explicitly via `session_write_close()`.

If not, look for other things that are locking resources.

Comment: I use exec to call this script.

Comment: Your main PHP file calls `exec()` on another PHP file? If so, that doesn't really change things. It still has to wait for it to finish, unless you run the executed process detached from the server. Also note, your browser will only make a certain number of simultaneous requests to the same domain, but that probably isn't the problem here (unless you are doing more thing than you have told us about).

Comment: When I request test.php with the above code it does not hang, but when I call it via exec: @exec('wget -q  -o /dev/null -a /dev/null -O /home/linux/test.txt http://127.0.0.1/test.php'); it hangs

Comment: Try adding `nohup` at the beginning. e.g., 'nohup wget ... &'. You really should edit your question to better explain what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for the link. After reading I realized that I need to call session_write_close() after I use the data, because all pages were session handled (the reason I could not open anyting because php waits for session to be closed after execution of the the script in background.